# Can reaching MaxConnectionsPerChild cause a 500 error?

Tags: apache, server

I'm trying to find the cause of a 500 Internal Server Error that comes up seemingly randomly, then goes away.

When I look at the Apache error log I don't see anything that explicitly says "Internal Server Error" during the past few months. However I do see a lot of instances like this:

> [Mon Jul 17 07:19:37.246018 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7768:tid 652] AH00358: Child: Process exiting because it reached
>   MaxConnectionsPerChild. Signaling the parent to restart a new child
>   process.
>
> [Mon Jul 17 07:19:37.246018 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7548:tid 716] AH00424: Parent: Received restart signal -- Restarting the
>   server.

The documentation I've found just says that when you hit `MaxConnectionsPerChild` the child process is restarted to avoid leaking memory.

I don't know much about this type of thing, but is that the cause of the following message saying that the server was restarted, and would that restart throw a momentary 500 error for users?

Comment: No, it would exit as soon as the limit is reached, and the next request would be directed to another available child, or new child if the others are all busy serving other clients. If the max number of children is reached, the request goes to the backlog and will be served as soon as a child is free (or timeout if none is free after the timeout period is reached)

Comment: @Capsule  That makes sense to me in theory, but every single time I see that MaxChildNodes error it's followed by that other message about restarting the server. I saw that probably 50 times. What's that about?

Comment: To be honest I have no experience with Apache on Windows... the `mpm_winnt` process manager might be buggy. A 500 error due to a process crash is very hard to debug because it's not logged. Maybe try to increase the log level and see if you get more granular info